# Add and Remove layout between two childs at run time in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

I want to add a layout between two childs at run time and then remove. Can you please give any idea to do this.

Herewith I attached the xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp">



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Show layer"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <!--
        Here I want to add and remove the Frame Layout at run time. I don't want to use
        Visible state for this layout. Need to Add and Remove the layout at runtime.
        -->

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Layer"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                />


        </FrameLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried addView(). But I can not add between the button and the layout.

Comment: Why `Button` is inside two `ViewGroup`? Pls add layout xml with question.

Comment: can you add some code and what you tried?

Comment: @PiyushMaheswari.. Added the code. I tried addView(). But I can not add the View between the Button and Layout.

Comment: @ADM .. When I click that button one layer will be displayed with animation.

Comment: you can use ViewStub in this case.